# Unable to pass multiple values through Ajax $.get()

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Hope you all fine.I am facing some sort of problem while passing multiple parameters through `$.get()`.

I want to pass "`coord.left`" and "`coord.top`" coordinates of a drag-able object through `$.get()` so I can store these coords into my databse. 
When I am passing a single parameter it is working fine but facing problem while passing multiple values.
Here is my code:

```
.mouseup(function(){

    var coords=[];
    var coord = $(this).position();
    var item={ coordTop:  coord.top, coordLeft: coord.left  };
    coords.push(item);
    var order = { coords: coords };
$.get('updatecoords.php', 'left='+coord.left, 'top='+coord.top function(response){
            alert("Data Loaded: " + coord.left + coord.top);
                    }); 
            });

    });
```

and here is my updatecoords.php file where I am pushing these values into database:

```
    $xleft = $_GET["left"];
    $ytop = $_GET["top"];

    //update query
    $sql = "UPDATE coords SET x_pos = '$xleft', y_pos = '$ytop'";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's about

```
$.get('updatecoords.php', {left=coord.left, top=coord.top}, function(response){
            alert("Data Loaded: " + coord.left + coord.top);
                    });
```

or

```
 $.get('updatecoords.php', {"left="+coord.left+"&top="+coord.top}, function(response){
                alert("Data Loaded: " + coord.left + coord.top);
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it should be `"left="+coord.left+"&top="+coord.top`.

Answer (score 0):

I also would recommend setting the $sql var like this :

```
$sql = "UPDATE coords SET `x_pos` = '" . $xleft . "', `y_pos` = '" . $ytop . "'";
```

Having variables inside simple quotes is usually a bad practice.